# Why remove a script after injecting it, via a Google Chrome extension, into an pre-existing webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I, like many, learnt how to use Google Chrome extensions to inject scripts into pre-existing webpages from Rob W's excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).

One thing I've become curious about is this part of his code:

`s.onload = function() {
    this.remove();
};`

Why do we need to remove the script after injecting it? I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's an attempt to reduce observable side-effects.

E.g. a webpage might have some code to check how many script tags are on the page, or expect a certain number of script tags to be present.

In practice it probably doesn't matter at all whether you remove the injected script or not.